# Mysql: event table :chronological consecutive join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
user_id | Membership_type | start_Date
1       |         1       |      1
1       |         1       |      2
1       |         2       |      3
1       |         3       |      4
```

with several users, and i need to find out for each user when the membership type changes and what the change is, in the following format (start date is datetime, put it here in int for ease of understanding)

```
user_id |Membership_change| change_Date
1       |      1 to 2     |     3
1       |      2 to 3     |     4
```

I have tried

```
select m1.user_id, concat(m1.Membership_type, ' to ',m2.Membership_type), m2.start_date
from table_membership m1 
join table_membership m2
on m1.user_id=m2.user_id and m1.start_date<m2.start_date and m1.membership_type<>m2.membership_type
```

but this will return

```
user_id |Membership_change| change_Date
1       |      1 to 2     |     3
1       |      1 to 2     |     3
1       |      1 to 3     |     4
1       |      2 to 3     |     4
```

The duplicate 1 to 2 is not a problem to remove through a grouping, but I cannot seem to be able to think of a way to avoid having the 1 to 3 result. I basically just need to join chronologically from one membership to the next

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Edit: Had an idea to add the column m1.start_date and group by account_id and m1.start_date, so I would only get the first row where each entry is joined. Also a pre-sort by date before the joins, to make sure they are all in order. Will test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an idea to add the column m1.start_date and group by account_id and m1.start_date, so I would only get the first row where each entry is joined. Also a pre-sort by date before the joins, to make sure they are all in order.

```
select m.user_id, m.membership_change, m.change_date from
(
select
  m1.user_id,
  concat(m1.Membership_type, ' to ',m2.Membership_type) as membership_change,
  m2.start_date as change_date, 
m1.start_date
from (select * from table_membership order by start_date asc)m1
  join (select * from table_membership order by start_date asc)m2
    on m1.user_id = m2.user_id
      and m1.start_date < m2.start_date
      and m1.membership_type <> m2.membership_type
GROUP BY m1.user_id,  m1.start_Date
)m group by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing GROUP BY

```
select
  m1.user_id,
  concat(m1.Membership_type, ' to ',m2.Membership_type),
  m2.start_date
from table_membership m1
  join table_membership m2
    on m1.user_id = m2.user_id
      and m1.start_date < m2.start_date
      and m1.membership_type <> m2.membership_type
GROUP BY user_id, Membership_change, change_Date
```

Comment: This would still leave the 1 to 3 result which is not desired, since it is not the chronological order. User had a membership type 1, then 1 again, then changed from 1 to 2, then changed from 2 to 3. I just need the chronologically logical changes

Comment: have you checked because we are grouping with Membership_change too

Comment: Yes, since 1 to 3 is unique and you are grouping on it, it will be kept